# Is it really legitimate to denote non-existence of an element as that element being an element of the empty set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My question is simple, but it bugs me...

I've seen many people using e.g. $a\in\emptyset$ to state that element $a$ does not exist... Is this legitimate? And why? I thought nothing can be an element of the empty set, by definition.

Comment: Can you give an example of this usage in context?

Comment: Sure, let's say that $a$ is the limit of some function and I want to state that it does not exist.

Comment: The fact that nothing can be an element of $\emptyset$ means $a$ does not exist...

Comment: Well, that makes sense, thank you!

Comment: $a\in\emptyset$ is simply a false statement, as is $P\land\neg P$. As such it can be used as part of a proof by contradiction, albeit an unusual one, I'd say.

Comment: An unusually tiny proof by contradiction, exactly what came into my mind after reading these comments!

Comment: A roundabout, too-symbol-heavy way of saying that the set of such $a$ is empty?

Comment: Just to emphasize something Henning already mentioned in his answer: it makes no formal sense to say "$a$ does not exist"---existence is not a predicate, but a quantifier.  Instead one should say "there does not exist $a$ such that..."

Comment: I have seen students use this. Presumably it is a habit they pick up from some standard high school text(s). In principle there is nothing wrong with it. Personally I would prefer "there ain't no such thing."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend this as a general notation for "$a$ does not exist" (or more precisely "there is no $a$ with the properties we have assumed"). Mostly because it is somewhat confusing, but also because the notation leaves it *implicit* which properties it is we have concluded $a$ cannot have.

Formally, $a\in\varnothing$ is simply another way to say "false" or "contradiction", because $\varnothing$ is *defined* such that $x\in\varnothing$ is always false.

This means, that if as part of an argument we have *assumed* that $a$ with such-and-such properties exists, and after some reasoning we reach $a\in\varnothing$, we can conclude that our assumption must have been false -- we have proved by contradiction that no $a$ can have these properties.

However, if we have assumed that $a$ with some properties exist, *and* that $b$ with some other properties exist, then if we reach $a\in\varnothing$, that doesn't tell us that it was $a$ in particular that doesn't exist -- it might as well have been the assumed properties on $b$ that lead to this contradiction.

Comment: Perhaps you should say explicitly in the third paragraph that the _only_ assumption we have made is that $a$ with such-and-such properties exists?

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following situation. The set $A=\{x\in \mathbb R \mid x^2 <0\}$ is the empty set. Now, suppose you want to find the real solutions of $x^2+1=0$. So, you can argue as follows: Assume that $y$ is a solution. Then $y^2=-1<0$ and therefore $y\in A$. But $A=\emptyset$ and so $y\notin A$, a contradiction. The contradiction stems from the assumption that a solution $y$ to $x^2+1=0$ exists and so we may conclude that such a solution does not exist.